# Display value from the database with inner join on laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to display all the products that are in my database,in products table I store id of 4 tables for the colors, types, product_types, brands
On my initial project I used:
"SELECT * FROM `product` join `brand` on product.brand_id = brand.id join `product_type` on product.product_type_id = product_type.id join `type` on product.type_id = type.id WHERE product.is_deleted = '0'";
Now I am trying to do the same but on Laravel 8 but I get the following error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
In App\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php (at start I used just the code below but without join and it worked, well i could not display color_name or anything from those tables )

```
public function index()
    {

        return view('admin.product.product',[
            'product' => Product::all()
                                    ->join('brand', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
        ]);
    }
```

And on product.blade.php(display page of the products)

```
@php
    $nr = 1;
@endphp
@foreach ($product as $row_product)
<tr>
    <td><p><?=$nr++?></p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->product_name }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->brand_name }}</p></td>
    <td><p>$ {{ $row_product->price }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->year }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->product_type_name }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->type_name }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->description }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product->created_at }} ({{ $row_product->created_at->diffForHumans() }}) </p></td>
    <td><p>Added By</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ $row_product['updated_at'] }} ({{ $row_product->updated_at->diffForHumans() }})</p></td>
    <td><p>Modified By</p></td>
    <td>
        <form action="/admin/product/{{ $row_product->product_id }}" method="POST" class="">
            @csrf
            @method('delete')
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{ route('edit_product',$row_product->product_id) }}">Edit</a>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary ms-0" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">Delete</button>
            {{-- <a class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2" href="admin.php?page=product_size_color_list&id=<//?=$row['product_id']?>">Product variants</a> --}}
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am doing wrong ? And how I can display products with an inner join cause right now I am out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has two *join* functions, you need [this other](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins), like that:

```php
Product::join('brand', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id');
```

You could add a field using *select* method.

```php
Product::join('brand', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id')->select('products.*', 'brand.name as brand_name');
```

The [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join) that was used in your code, joins the collection's values with a string.

Comment: Not working i get "Call to a member function select() on string"

Comment: You right! we confuse `join` method. The `join` that we use was [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join). But the `join` that we need was [that](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins).

Comment: found a solution, I will post the update in a few hours